# ClaimType.GivenName doesn't return my first name

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I am developing .net core 2.2 application that authenticates from Azure AD. I would like to get the user's first name in the _LoginPartial.cshtml in RAZOR web app. I am able to get the user's surname and email but not the first name. Is there away to get this?

This is what i have in my login partial view:

```
Claim nameClaim = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault<Claim>(claim => string.Compare(claim.Type, "name", StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0);
    string userName = (nameClaim != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameClaim.Value) ? nameClaim.Value : ((User != null) && (User.Identity != null) ? User.Identity.Name : string.Empty);
```

Also i tried this:

```
@User.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value
```

The given name returns email same as name and email properties!!

What would be the ideal way to get the first name by extending the identity model in asp.net?

Answer (score 2):

For Identity, there is no `FirstName` in the built-in `IdentityUser`, you need to implement your own user like:

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, implement `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>`

```
public class CustomClaimsIdentityFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
    public CustomClaimsIdentityFactory(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
        , IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor) 
        : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
        //custom claims
        ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] {
          new Claim("FirstName", user.FirstName)
          });
        return principal;
    }
}
```

Then, you could check the `FirstName` by `@User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "FirstName")?.Value` like

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using TestIdentity.Data
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "FirstName")?.Value!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form  class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
            <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in asp.net core 2.2 since the current middle ware doesn't have SignInManager or UserManager as we used to have in standard mvc asp.net web apps.

Comment: @Mostafa Have you tried with `@User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "FirstName")?.Value` in your project? It is not necessary to use `SignInManager` or `UserManager`

Comment: I did try it and i get empty string!

Comment: @Mostafa Did you use asp.net core identity? Has `Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)` be hit? Could you share us a demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I resolved the issue. the dev tenant was having info and once i corrected this, the initial code i shared works like a champ! thanks for your help.